# Ideal way to write JSON objects in new lines to a text file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a text file in which each line contains one JSON object. The JSON objects can be very different from each others, i.e., may have different structure.

I read the file and decide which object I'd like to keep and write that object to another text file like this.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            myJSON = json.loads(line)
            if "myProperty" in myJSON:
                    json.dump(myJSON, outfile)
                    outfile.write('\n')
```

I'd like to know whether writing a newline explicitly is the recommended way to writing each JSON object in a separate line or should I do it differently. 
I need to writing in this format only as without this newline everything goes into a single line in the output file and it't not very useful that way.

Comment: This question probably fits better on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not a very good method. The problem is that it will fail as soon as you have a json object that contains a newline character itself.

Comment: @wvdz: which would be escaped if inside a string. `json.dump()` does not, by default, produce JSON documents with newlines.

Comment: what do you do with the new file? You need to read it again, you need to process it as JSON, etc. The answer basically depends on your use case.

Comment: @lesingerouge And yes I need to re read it and do further processing, and re reading it works fine so it does work as the way I want it to.

Comment: @wvdz There are no \n in my JSON objects.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for the tip. :) Will use that from now on.